# ASP.Net Core 3 Sort Foreign Key Drop down Select Lists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have Two different ASP.net Core 3 applications that are running which have Tables linked to other tables with foreign keys.  In the CRUD pages the Drop down lists work properly and display the data but the data is sorted in the order of the primary key, which is typically an integer index key.  I am hoping to figure out how to display these dropdown lists in sort order based on the values being displayed.  I have not found any commands that do the job.  Any help would be appreciated.  The foreign Keys for Projects are Street and TownProperty. I will attach the code files;

Projects Controller.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TOGProjects.Models;

namespace TOGProjects.Controllers
{
    public class ProjectsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly TOGProjectsContext _context;

        public ProjectsController(TOGProjectsContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Projects
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var tOGProjectsContext = _context.Projects.Include(p => p.Street).Include(p => p.TownProperty);
            return View(await tOGProjectsContext.ToListAsync());
        }

        // add Search ablity on the Index Page
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(String Projectsearch)
        {
            ViewData["GetProjectDetails"] = Projectsearch;

            var projectquery = _context.Projects
                                    .Include(s => s.Street)
                                    .Include(s => s.TownProperty)
                                    .AsQueryable();



            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Projectsearch))
            {
                projectquery = projectquery.Where(x => x.ProjectDescription.Contains(Projectsearch) || x.Pwnum.Contains(Projectsearch));
            }
            return View(await projectquery.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Projects/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var projects = await _context.Projects
                .Include(p => p.Street)
                .Include(p => p.TownProperty)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ProjectId == id);
            if (projects == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(projects);
        }

        // GET: Projects/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["StreetId"] = new SelectList(_context.StreetNames, "StreetId", "Streets");
            ViewData["TownPropertyId"] = new SelectList(_context.TownProperties, "TownPropertyId", "TownPropertyName");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Projects/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ProjectId,ProjectDescription,DateStarted,Pwnum,StreetId,StateProjectNumber,TownPropertyId,CapitalAccount")] Projects projects)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(projects);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["StreetId"] = new SelectList(_context.StreetNames, "StreetId", "Streets", projects.StreetId);
            ViewData["TownPropertyId"] = new SelectList(_context.TownProperties, "TownPropertyId", "TownPropertyName", projects.TownPropertyId);
            return View(projects);
        }

        // GET: Projects/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var projects = await _context.Projects.FindAsync(id);
            if (projects == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            ViewData["StreetId"] = new SelectList(_context.StreetNames, "StreetId", "Streets", projects.StreetId);
            ViewData["TownPropertyId"] = new SelectList(_context.TownProperties, "TownPropertyId", "TownPropertyName", projects.TownPropertyId);
            return View(projects);
        }

        // POST: Projects/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ProjectId,ProjectDescription,DateStarted,Pwnum,StreetId,StateProjectNumber,TownPropertyId,CapitalAccount")] Projects projects)
        {
            if (id != projects.ProjectId)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(projects);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!ProjectsExists(projects.ProjectId))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["StreetId"] = new SelectList(_context.StreetNames, "StreetId", "Streets", projects.StreetId);
            ViewData["TownPropertyId"] = new SelectList(_context.TownProperties, "TownPropertyId", "TownPropertyName", projects.TownPropertyId);
            return View(projects);
        }

        // GET: Projects/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var projects = await _context.Projects
                .Include(p => p.Street)
                .Include(p => p.TownProperty)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ProjectId == id);
            if (projects == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(projects);
        }

        // POST: Projects/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var projects = await _context.Projects.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Projects.Remove(projects);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool ProjectsExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Projects.Any(e => e.ProjectId == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Projects.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TOGProjects.Models
{
    public partial class Projects
    {
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Project Description")]
        [Required, StringLength(50)]
        [RegularExpression(@"(([A-za-z0-9\s\-]+))$")]
        public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Date Started")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? DateStarted { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Engineering Project Number")]
        public string Pwnum { get; set; }
        public int? StreetId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("State Project Number")]
        [StringLength(15)]
        public string StateProjectNumber { get; set; }
        public int? TownPropertyId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Capital Account")]
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string CapitalAccount { get; set; }

        public virtual StreetNames Street { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Town Property Name")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public virtual TownProperties TownProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Projects Index.cshtml

```
@model TOGProjects.Models.Projects

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>Projects</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="ProjectId" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProjectDescription" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProjectDescription" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProjectDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DateStarted" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DateStarted" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DateStarted" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Pwnum" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Pwnum" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Pwnum" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StreetId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="StreetId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.StreetId"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="StreetId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StateProjectNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="StateProjectNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="StateProjectNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="TownPropertyId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="TownPropertyId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.TownPropertyId"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="TownPropertyId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CapitalAccount" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CapitalAccount" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CapitalAccount" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add an `OrderBy` to your data like below.

```
ViewData["StreetId"] = new SelectList(_context.StreetNames.OrderBy(s => s.Streets), "StreetId", "Streets");
ViewData["TownPropertyId"] = new SelectList(_context.TownProperties.OrderBy(t => t.TownPropertyName), "TownPropertyId", "TownPropertyName");
```

Comment: Worked perfectly on both of the apps I have converted to asp.net Mac core, Thanks